# Sharing Files Between a Website and Cordova Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

We are writing a web application (standard MVC for now) and a companion mobile/tablet application using the new visual studio tools for cordova.  Many of the assets, images, css, and even the javascript and HTML can be shared between the applications.

I've tried using the "Add As Link" to add an image that "lives" in the MVC app to the images used by the cordova app.  However, when the cordova app is built any files that were included using the "Add As Link" option don't appear in the output.

I'd really rather not have to have some build step copy files around as it could quickly turn into a maintenance headache.  Is there some configuration I can tweak to make linked files build correctly in cordova projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently only the files physically present under project directory is picked for deployment and packaging.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a simple msbuild target that simply copies the linked files as a pre build step